# Completely uninstall VS Code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since the latest release of VS Code, I get an error whenever I open a C# file (I have installed the csharp language extension, powered by OmniSharp). This is the error I get:

[image]

I tried uninstalling the extension and re-install it, same problem. I uninstalled the application altogether and reinstalled it - but when I do that, my extensions are still installed (for instance Python and reStructuredText were still there). I uninstalled yet again and deleted the `%USER%\AppData\Roaming|Local\Code` directory. When I reinstalled, the extensions were still there.

How do I completely remove the installed extensions? I'd like to be sure I'm starting from scratch before opening a bug for the OmniSharp extension crash.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Turns out the extensions are stored under %USER%\.vscode\extensions. Deleting that gets rid of them.

For Windows:
`%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

Location of extensions for Linux/MAC:
`~/.vscode/extensions`

Comment: Why are extensions themselves allowed to litter across the filesystem **even after extension is uninstalled**?
 for example, I downloaded a restclient and it writes to `~/.rest-client` instead of keeping it to the  `~/.vscode/extensions/*` folder...

Comment: Deleting these and re-installing fixed all of my extension issues. So thankful for this post.

Comment: @Pacerier because VSCode extensions are arbitrary JavaScript code that runs in an unrestricted (non-sandboxed) Node.js environment by Electron, and there is no way to limit what a extension can do with this architecture.

Comment: Worked great, thanks. I've been trying to get rid of copilot but it kept reinstalling itself, now it's finally gone. Hopefully never to be seen again

Comment: It worked great, but beware it will remove all extensions and you might want to do it for only specific items which had issues in uninstalling or something. So better to keep a backup list of required extensions. so you can install it after removing all.
hope it will some someone's time.

Answer (score 92):

All the answers above are correct, but for a beginner, I wanted to add that all you have to do is, run this command in your terminal to remove **ALL** extensions/themes.

**For Mac/Linux**

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode/extensions
```

**For Windows**

```
rmdir %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions /s
```

Comment: That's the questions being asked here.

Comment: This is incorrect, or only "partially correct". Please see @Pacerier comment further up saying extensions appear in other folders as well. These commands will clean up the extensions living in those places but not others. For me I had to manually eyeball hidden folders (shift + cmd + .  to show hidden)  in '~/` to find hidden folders matching extensions. I'm still looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 35):

You can remove them at:

- **Windows**: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- **Mac**: `~/.vscode/extensions`
- **Linux**: `~/.vscode/extensions`

Answer (score 19):

It worked for me, but the enviroment variable was `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Linux then try:

```
code --list-extensions | while read extension;
do
 code --uninstall-extension $extension --force
done
```

On Windows you can do (not try ):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %f in (`code --list-extensions`) do code --uninstall-extension %f --force
```

Or this with Powershell:

```
code --list-extensions | % { code --uninstall-extension --force $_  }
```

Comment: works for mac weither

Comment: Perfect - Your top command works for Mac with code in PATH

Answer (score 11):

One line variant of [Ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394467/12671715):

```bash
code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 code --uninstall-extension
```

Comment: That's the best answer in the age of sync'ed settings.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove a VSCode Extension in Windows 10 on WSL2 completely, then you need to look in a few additional directories:

~/.vscode-server/data/CachedExtensionVSIXs/ 
~/.vscode-server/data/User/globalStorage/ 
~/.vscode-server/extensions/

Comment: .vscode-server comes up in machines where you have sshed into using "Remote SSH" extension...

Answer (score 5):

If you work with VS Code-Insiders extensions in folder: **Windows**

> %USERPROFILE%.vscode-insiders\extension

**MAC/Linux:**

> ~/.vscode-insiders/extensions

Answer (score 3):

use following command

```
code --list-extensions | foreach { code --uninstall-extension $_ }
```

Comment: Awesome, some explication would be good, but this works perfectly in PowerShell for Visual Studio Code in Windows

Answer (score 2):

I found the following to be effective:

First, locate the extension ID:

```
code --list-extensions
```

Then, uninstall it:

```
code --uninstall-extension ID
```

Note: You must replace the ID with the ID you discovered in step one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem after **switching from 32-bit vscode to 64-bit** versions of the vscode app, causing the C# extension uninstall-install flow to break in vscode.

I saw the folder `~\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.7-win32-ia32` (notice the `-ia32` because 32-bit vscode had downloaded the x86 32-bit version.) After I deleted this folder then installed 64-bit vscode, trying to install the C# extension using the app's GUI or `code` CLI seemed to work, except after I opened vscode then ***it couldn't find the extension!***

The **fix** was to open `~\.vscode\extensions\extensions.json` and **delete the JSON entry for `ms-dotnettools.csharp`** which still pointed at the 32-bit extension. After deleting this part of the JSON file, installing C# extension from the GUI worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac

```
Finder -> Go to Folder -> Go
```

[image]
[image]

Paste the directory `~/.vscode/extensions`

**Your are in your destination.**

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to find your resources of vscode.
The resources usually located in /usr/share (linux).
So you have to cd to /usr/share/code/resources/app to see extensions directory.
Now, you just use rm -rf extensions to remove extensions directory.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows - Users\username.vscode\extensions
You may delete what extensions you don't want.
And Click on hidden items then follow the below instructions -
This PC -> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs and
delete file which you uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

All work for me, but there is an issue need to fix to get the directory on Windows use:

> %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extension,

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of some extension so uninstall it.

First go to extensions tab and then click the 3 dots in the top right corner then disable all extensions and check if the sound is gone or not .
If yes then find the extension which was causing the problem and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue on a laptop that I had **migrated** my settings from a previous one and maybe had some corrupted extension or something. I ended up uninstalling vscode and then manually deleting the roaming code folder completely.

- `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code`

Then after reinstalling and I was able to install the extension afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Once the extensions folder within .vscode-server directory is deleted, you might get the following error when trying to install extensions again.

*Unable to read file '/home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/extensions.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/extensions.json')*

To resolve this, you might as well as have to recreate some deleted files.

```
mkdir -p /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions  
touch /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/extensions.json
```

Try installing the extensions and everything should work.