# OmniSharp throws errors when test was quit unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have been facing this annoying error for a while which looks like following:

`Failed to start debugger: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object\n at OmniSharp.DotNetTest.TestManager.SendMessage[T]`

It occurs when a test was quit in debug session because of some error and I think that puts OmniSharp.Csharp module in some weird state. I tried re-installing the OmniSharp plug-in and restarting visual studio code but seems like error just does not go away.

I have OmniSharp C# version 1.31.1. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you are experiencing a bug. Try to upgrade OmniSharp as it is now at version 1.16...https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases

Comment: Its interesting because, In my extensions tab, when I look at Omnisharp.C#, it does not look like it needs an update. Also, when I do clean install, instead of installing the latest version, it does install 1.13.1. How do I upgrade it?

Comment: It is not published to the online repository yet, that's why it only installs 1.13

Comment: Download the vsix file...https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/download/v1.16.0/csharp-1.16.0.vsix 
Then double click to install...

Comment: However i get an error if i try to install 1.16 on my dev system

Comment: @AnyMoose I updated both my VSCode and Omnisharp and still facing the same error. Is there any way I can delete omnisharp related cache/settings from the file system? I think it is picking something up from the old version's settings

Comment: Try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions

Comment: @AnyMoose: This did work. Thank you :)