# VS Code Go Extension Corrupting File On Save

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

This is driving me crazy. I'm using VS Code as my IDE for Go development. About every third or so time I save my changes, it corrupts the file by removing random characters. I have tried [manually removing all extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions), uninstalled VS Code, re-installed VS Code, and installed only the Go extension, but it still keeps happening. Based on what's happening, I guess I can isolate it to the Go extension, but I'm not seeing any other posts associated with the behavior. Is anyone else experiencing this and, if so, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you file a bug at vs code, it might the vs code issue, not the extension. Also what OS you are using.

Comment: Try to save with open console in developer tools (Help -> Toggle Developer tools -> Console) or/and with open logs (View -> Command Palllete... -> Show Logs)

Comment: That's a very strange symptom. Are you saving to a local drive, or are you editing over a network or anything like that? Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned that I'm on Windows 10 and I'm saving locally. I'll try the suggestions and report back.

Comment: @BillChen I'll file a bug, but I'm not noticing it happening in other extensions like PowerShell or NSIS, so it doesn't look like a vs code issue.

Answer (score 0):

This [VSCode bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/3008) addresses the issue.