# GitHub command 'github.copilot.generate' not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I have installed GitHub Copilot I have got an access to use it too but when I try CTRL + Enter I get this error message:

```
command 'github.copilot.generate' not found
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but still no change.

**Edit**: I discovered that GitHub copilot actually works on my laptop, but not on my desktop even though they are signed in to the same account that has access to use the extension. I tried completely deleting vs code from the laptop but it didn't help too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Copilot Commands not working and showing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253302/github-copilot-commands-not-working-and-showing-error)

Comment: none of it worked for me

Comment: Any chance you are connected to a VPN on the computer it's not working? I have the same issue and when I tried disconnecting from my work VPN copilot worked (I restarted copilot after disconnecting)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows

1. Go to `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/Code/CachedExtensionVSIXs`
2. Delete all copilot files and reopen vsCode.

Comment: `command 'github.copilot.generate' not found`