# VS Code crashing on start

Tags: visual-studio-code, crash, windows-10

For the past week or so VS Code has crashed every time I try to start it. I will see the outline of a window and then a "The window is not responding" prompt with options "Reopen" "Keep waiting" "close".

If I choose to keep waiting the same prompt shows up after a few seconds. If I hit Reopen I get a new prompt that says "The window has crashed (reason: 'crashed', code: '2')". I can then choose to "Reopen" (which goes back to the first prompt) or "Close".

I've searched around on google for a solution but nothing has worked. I have tried reinstalling to no avail. I am running Windows 10. Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try installing visual studio code insiders. It is the same as vscode just that new features come to it faster. (yes it is official)

Comment: Uninstall all extensions you have installed.

Comment: That seems to have worked @Aviral! Thanks!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how is he gonna uninstall extensions without opening vscode which isn't opening :/

Comment: @Aviral E.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just tried that. I had 1 extension installed (bitlang.cobol-7.7.22). I deleted the folder but still got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Aviral suggested, installing VS Code Insider works as a work around for this problem.