# Cannot launch debugger for azure function app in vs code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to debug an azure function app in VSCode using Python in a Windows10 environment. Whenever I launch the debugger it hangs for a long period of time and then opens a message box that says

> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091

There are a bunch of posts about this but none seem helpful/can solve the problem. Here is what I've tried:

- uninstalling and re-installing different versions of
  azure-function-core-tools using windows installer, npm and chocolatey
- uninstalling and re-installing Azure Functions extension in VS Code
- changing the extension bundle

```
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
```

- modifying local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", 
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

- deleting C:\Users\admin.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles
- creating a function app from command line using "func init" and lauching  debugger by running "func host start" in active venv

I am using Python38 and really have no idea what else to try. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Try restoring your `launch.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution at:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3160#issuecomment-1266273749

I ran command func start in verbose mode

```
func start --verbose
```

from there it was clear that the process timed out when trying to download a new extension bundle. Most likely due to slow internet. I manually installed the new extension bundle:

https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/3.15.0/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.3.15.0_any-any.zip

(the full path should be in the --verbose output) and extracted to

C:\Users[user name].azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.15.0

It now works. Thanks everyone for input.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot launch debugger for azure function app in VScode-
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091

This type of generic error may occur for a variety of reasons.

**Need to check and modify**:

1. First and foremost, check whether the versions of `Azure functions core tools` and `Pip` are upgraded to the current version:

   To upgrade pip:

   ```py
     python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   ```

   To install and upgrade azure-functions:

   ```py
    pip install azure-functions
   ```
2. Go to the below path,
   `view -> Command palette -> User Settings`

[image]

[Python functions, task runFunctionsHost windows command only work with powershell](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/855):
Set the integrated > default profile: Windows to PowerShell as *PowerShell runtime host is functional with Python functions*. It was previously set to "null".

[image]

3. > The debug configuration is specified in your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` files in the `.vscode` folder.

As stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/892) , the default listening port in launch.json is set to 9091. Here, I updated it to `"port: 7071"` which is open for traffic on my function project, launched the files, and then executed the "Attach to Python Functions" debug task once again.

*Under `.VScode folder -> launch.json` file, this configuration changes works for me.*

***launch.json:***

```py
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "python_modules./.bin/func",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
   {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 7071,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
   }
 ]
 }
```

[image]

*Added multiple debug points, debugged and triggered successfully as shown below:*

[image]

Also Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532944/unable-to-debug-python-azure-function-in-vs-code-ide-getting-connect-econnrefus) for more approaches given by @Hari Krishna