# How do I debug a FastAPI Azure Function App in VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions, fastapi

**The problem**

I have created an application which utilizes FastAPI and Azure Function Apps by following the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/

However, I am unable to get debugging to work. The function host does successfully start, but the debugger is unable to connect. I receive the pop-up error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091`.

I am on a Windows 10 system using Python 3.9.13, functions core tools v4, packages `azure-functions`, `nest_asyncio`, `fastapi`, and `uvicorn`. I am using the latest versions of the VSCode extensions `Azure Functions v1.10.3` and `Python v2023.2.0`.

**What I have tried**

I have attempted to enable reload and debugging for uvicorn following the FastAPI guide at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/ with no luck.

Attempting to configure the `--language-worker` of the `func start` or `func host start` command results in the same error if using `ptvsd` or a failure to locate Python if attempting to use `-m uvicorn --reload --debug`.

**Code** As found in the aforementioned guide:

*tasks.json*

```json
{
  "type": "func",
  "command": "host start",
  "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
  "isBackground": true,
  "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
},
```

*launch.json*

```json
{
  "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 9091,
  "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be various causes of the error `**ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091**`.

you can refer to SO #[71532944](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71534944) given by the user @*HariKrishna* for the various resolutions to fix this error during debugging process in Azure Functions in VS Code.

I have reproduced the issue in my environment by taking code from [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/) repository which is available in the same MSDOC you have given in the question, and I could get the below results as shown below:

[image]

**Output:**
[image]