# Completely uninstall VS Code extensions in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, lldb

I cannot uninstall a certain VS Code extension ([CodeLLDB](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb)) that is installed in my WSL. If I try with the VS Code GUI after reopening the program the extension is still there. If I try with the console the same thing happens.

I tried the following, as some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions) recommended:

```
$ code --list-extensions
vadimcn.vscode-lldb
```

That is the extension I want to uninstall, so I run:

```
$ code --uninstall-extension vadimcn.vscode-lldb --force
Uninstalling vadimcn.vscode-lldb...
Extension 'vadimcn.vscode-lldb' was successfully uninstalled!
```

But if I list them again it is still there:

```
$ code --list-extensions
vadimcn.vscode-lldb
```

###### Some extra details:

I use WSL 2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found that the extensions where installed in my WSL2 in the directory `~/.vscode-server/extensions/` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66135457/18184432) says, so the way to uninstall it is:

```
$ cd ~/.vscode-server/extensions/
$ rm -rf <extension-name>
```