# VS Code's Intellisense for C++ not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having problems getting VS Code’s Intellisense for C++ to work.
I am using Windows 10, g++ and gdb. I have installed the extensions *C/C++ for Visual Studio Code* and the *C/C++ Extension Pack*.

If I write *msg*, for example, *main, mitl, module* and *mutable* will appear, but that’s it - essentially, I get a partial list. The subsequent ‘s’ and ‘g’ of msg produce nothing nor does the normally triggering dot or full stop after msg (msg.) Even the simplest *printf* produces only *private, protected*, and *pragma*, but *printf* is never an option.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code to no avail. I have also deleted all extensions and reinstalled them as per [Completely uninstall VS Code extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions), again, without success. A simple piece of code compiled without issue, but when I changed the source code file for something a little more complicated the following messages appeared.

*Please update #include errors detected. Please update your includePAth. IntelliSense features fro this translation unit(C/NOTES/Programming/VSCODE/helloworld.cp) will be provided by the tag parser*

*[2/1/2023, 10:54:07 PM] For C++ source files, IntelliSenseMode was changed from "windows-gcc-x64" to "windows-msvc-x64" based on compiler args and querying compilerPath: "C:\ghcup\ghc\9.2.5\mingw\bin\gcc.exe"

[2/1/2023, 10:54:07 PM] For C source files, IntelliSenseMode was changed from "windows-gcc-x64" to "windows-msvc-x64" based on compiler args and querying compilerPath: "C:\ghcup\ghc\9.2.5\mingw\bin\gcc.exe"*

Is it a case of IntelliSense looking at the C compiler (gcc.exe) and not the C++ compiler (g++.exe) and if so how can I change that?

Comment: Provide a [mre] of the code-completion scenario and say what you expect to see.

Comment: The new messages from VS Code (see above) may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Where are the standard library headers located in your installation of g++? Edit to add the output from following the instructions in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940219/11107541).